# My custom httpModule is not being detected with MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, httpmodule

I've created a custom module:

```
namespace KittenFarm.ServerModules
{
    public class CustomServerHeaderModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PreSendRequestHeaders += OnPreSendRequestHeaders;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        { }

        void OnPreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
        }
    } 
}
```

And I've registered it in my web config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="CustomServerHeader" type="CustomServerHeaderModule" />
    </modules>
    ....
```

However, it never seems to run.

I suspected it was a namespace issue, but I have tried every combination of namespaces in the `type=` section I can think of and it never hits the breakpoint I put in it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the solution was set up to use the Visual Studio Development Server, which doesn't pick up the http modules. After I changed it to use my local IIS, it worked.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct, it is your namespace that is missing from the type.

The following worked for me:

```
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="CustomServerHeader" type="KittenFarm.ServerModules.CustomServerHeaderModule" />
   </modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your function to run before Application_Start method is called. Add below code in global.asax

[assembly:PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(CS.MVCHttpModule.MvcApplication),"Register")]

See http://dotnetlionet.blogspot.in/2015_06_01_archive.html